# How to secure the access to my Node-RED UI with httpNodeAuth

Tags: user-interface, authentication, node-red

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find a way to secure my Node-RED user interface. The UI can be accessed by anonymous users...

So far I have tried to set up the `settings.json` file and the `httpNodeAuth` part but nothing worked.

How can I limit access to the Node-RED UI?

Comment: What environment are you on, local machine or Bluemix? I assume started Node-RED after applying the changes.

Comment: of course.. i am running node-red directly on a raspberry pi zero w. i restarted node-red and also i restarted the device. no reaction

Comment: please share the settings.js file and which version of Node-RED you are using

Comment: Which copy of settings.js did you edit? the one being used by node-red is logged in the first 10 lines of output at startup

Comment: Node-RED version: v0.16.2 - this is the settings /home/pi/.node-red/settings.js and this is the content: [mysettings](https://pastebin.com/4XEARNQ2)

Comment: Rather than linking to your settings file, edit the question to include the relevant bits, e.g. the `httpNodeAuth` and `adminAuth` sections

Comment: Edit the question to explain how you serving your UI, is it static files or using http-in/http-response nodes?

Comment: i think it's static files

Comment: @data_henrik, and on Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you are working with the copy of `settings.js` in the `.node-red` directory in. This file and it's location will be logged when Node-RED starts

```
18 May 11:41:51 - [info] Settings file  : /home/hardillb/.node-red/settings.js
18 May 11:41:51 - [info] User directory : /home/hardillb/.node-red
18 May 11:41:51 - [info] Flows file     : /home/hardillb/.node-red/testing.json
18 May 11:41:51 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
18 May 11:41:51 - [info] Starting flows
```

Next do you want to secure the Node-RED Editor UI or the Dashboard UI?

If the Editor UI then you need to find the `adminAuth` section:

```
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
        username: "admin",
        password: "$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN.",
        permissions: "*"
    }]
},
```

You generate the password hash using the following command:

```
node-red-admin hash-pw
```

or

```
node -e "console.log(require('bcryptjs').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" [your-password-here]
```

If you want to secure the Dashboard UI then it's the `httpNodeAuth` option that needs changing.

```
httpNodeAuth: {user:"user",pass:"$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN."},
```

If you have enabled the service of static content using the `httpStatic` then this content is protected via the `httpStaticAuth` directive.

```
httpStaticAuth: {user:"user",pass:"$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN."}
```

The password hash in both cases is generated in the same way as for the `adminAuth` section.

The docs for securing Node-RED can be found here: http://nodered.org/docs/security

Comment: @komarek you have mixed quotes chars at the start and end of the strings in your `settings.json`. What did you use to edit it? (word and some other client uses "smart" quotes that are different at the start end)

Comment: i just used nano on the raspi.

Comment: it could be that when i posted it to pastebin i used the json format and possibly it made some mess.. where do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Around the username and hashed password

Comment: i don't think i understand you. what do you mean? you commented again the httpNodeAuth part.

Answer (score 2):

I FINALLY realized
it was a **cache** problem.
node-red seems to work really aggressive with cache.
thanks everybody for support

Comment: My question is what about the next time you log in? If you press the back button, you will find that that you can still access the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Rather late to this question. However, for future reference, the simplest and probably most secure way to add authentication to any specific or collection of end points served by Node-RED is to use a reverse proxy using something like NGINX, Caddy, HAProxy, etc.

They all make it relatively easy to add authentication to endpoints and do not rely on the complexity of ExpressJS settings to do so.